# Regular expressions: only accept digits between 0-9 along with the special characters `- ( ) +` and spaces

Tags: regex

I have to validate some user input and can only accept digits between 0-9 along with the special characters `- ( ) +` and spaces.

By way of rules:

1. The same special character (including spaces) can never appear twice consecutively, e.g. `((` `))` `++` `--` would all be invalid.
2. The string must start with either a `+` or `00`
3. A opening bracket must always proceed a closing bracket and enclose a number greater than 1 digit, e.g. `(1)` `(12)` `(123)` etc... are acceptable, whereas, `()`  `)(`  `( )` are not acceptable.

I am able to workout point 2 with `^([0][0]|[+])`

Comment: Are you already familiar with regex?  If not, I recommend www.regular-expressions.info to get you started and www.regexpal.com to test them out.

Comment: What language are you using this expression in?

Comment: try jQuery masking input plugin : http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Comment: Nope, I'm not familiar with it unfortunately. With regards to language, thats a difficult one; The regex is stored in a database and extracted a run time. It is then run as part of JQuery/Javascript for client-side validation and is also used server side (C#).

Comment: Is it possible to have nested parenthesis e.g. ([([123])])  ?

Comment: Nope you can't have nested parenthesis.

Comment: Are these inputs are valid? `+2+-+5`, `+++`, `00(-5)00`

Comment: Please workout the rule clarifications requested in comments in your answer (via editing).  We need to know these details as some interpretations of your original rules are impossible to handle with the regular expressions of many languages (they require a PDA\CFG).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Give this a shot:

`^(00|\+(?!\+))(\+(?!\+)|(\-(?!\-))|( (?! ))|(\([1-9][0-9]*\)))*$`

It follows each of your rules exactly as you specified.  If you didn't clarify your rules fully, it'll be hard for me to give you an accurate regex, but assuming you wrote down the exact rules, this should work!

Keep in mind that you have included an odd case where the string `+` is to be matched.  I'm not sure that was intentional.

This regex makes liberal use of negative lookahead.  Be sure to visit www.regular-expressions.info and www.regexpal.com to brush up on your regex skills!